# Are we going to switch to angular 2?

Tags: developer, angular

Angular has a new shiny version that seems to offer several new features and a faster experience.

https://angular.io/features.html
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/angular-2-introduction-to-redux-1cf18af27e6e#.pbxw78lb1

What is the plan for civi to migrate to angular2? The upgrade doesn't seem to be too complicated, but is there something to look at for the extensions?

I'm wondering if the switch should be done before 4.7 is stable, because changing a library in the 4.7.x seems to be a bit risky, but 4.8 is far away.

Comment: Since 4.7 is the last 4.x release this could be something to slate for 5.0. That would feel like good time to implement the upgrade anyway =]

Comment: Excellent question. but I think that the "doesn't seem too complicated" may not be too accurate.

Comment: haven't tried too much, on other projects, I've investigated vue.js and it felt more natural to me, so angular2 ain't my priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not be happening for 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5.x...

(NB I realise I may not be adding much to above comments but am trying to get some unanswered questions answered as that is currently the 'weakest' aspect of our Beta civicrm stackexchange according to these [stats][1])